# Has anyone ever come up with a way to detect the email program a recipient is using?

Tags: email-client

I know there are ways to detect browsers based on CSS rules but I don't know if the same tricks would work for Outlook. The way I think it could work is have CSS rules that show and hide urls so that when a recipient clicks on a link I can tell which email program it came from.

Comment: What if I use two different email programs? What if I have one connected to another (Outlook Connector for Hotmail, for instance)?

Comment: Neal Stephenson already did this. I think he called it an "e-mail ping". Or maybe I am thinking of another equally "technologically-blessed" author...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see how this would be possible. Browser detection is done via Javascript (not CSS). And if the user is using a non-web-based email client (such as Outlook), clicking on a link will trigger the default browser to open and load the link. The information the browser sends to your server will have no knowledge of what application caused the browser to launch.

I think your only option would be to have different links for each client and rely on the goodness of the users to click the correct link.

I also think you'd have a fairly high success rate of guessing the client based on a few factors that ARE available after the link is clicked such as:

- The device type
- The Browser
- The Operating System
- The email address (if it's gmail.com or hotmail.com you know 99% of them used the web client - or for a better match mix it with the device type)

Then you could make generalisations such as:

- Accessed from Windows and not a gmail/hotmail/yahoo webmail address - probably used Outlook
- Accessed from OSX and not webmail address - probably used Mail
- Accessed from either and a webmail address - probably used Browser

Rules like that could probably give you some pretty meaningful statistics.

Comment: I use Windows, and have never used Outlook (or any version of it) for email. Ever. Not even once. I have dozens of friends who can say the same thing. Windows (since Vista's release) doesn't even have a default email client out of the box. I use FireFox as a browser. I don't have a gmail or hotmail email address. You missed on all but the OS. Sorry. :)

Comment: @KenWhite: Posting this on a tech site was bound to get this kind of response - but outliers aside, especially taking into account the massive corporate audience, the vast majority of non-web-based email access from Windows would be from an Outlook variant. Have a look at the market share of this sucker: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/stats/email-clients/ . As I said, this isn't a 100% method but would give you results that are most likely indicative of reality.

Comment: @KenWhite: As for the browser, not sure what you're getting at, but I wasn't suggesting to differentiate client based on IE=Win, Safari=Mac as the browser market is much more differentiated. It would, however, help to indicate the device used to access the email and, thus, could help define rules to further refine the likely client.

Comment: My point was "relying on the goodness of the user" won't work. I click on a link by mistake, and you make assumptions based on 100% wrong information. That's not an outlier - that's a wrong assumption. Also, note I posted a comment, not a downvote. :) My point was that "you could guess based on facts that are meaningless" isn't really an answer to the question. It's not a reliable means of determining what the email client was that was in use. You'd do as well by saying "OK. We'll just decide that 100% of the people running Windows are using Outlook.".

Comment: (continued): I still know several **very** large organizations that (unfortunately) use Lotus Notes for email. How do they fit the "non-web-based email...would be an Outlook variant" model?

Comment: @KenWhite: My first sentence states I don't think it's possible. Then I went on to offer some solutions which may provide indicators. I work in BI - I have to do this all the time. Very rarely will you get 100% of the information you need, but if you can draw conclusions from other pieces that, for the vast majority of cases, correlate, then your results are still statistically significant. My answer to the question was the first sentence, my elaboration was based on experience. Statistics is rarely an exact art. BTW, I appreciate your feedback, there's no hard feelings. :)

Comment: None from me either. (As I said, I made a comment and not a vote.) :)

Answer (score 1):

If your challenge is to see what email client the person is using, there are simpler solutions than showing and hiding links. The easiest way would be to embed an image, add a query string to it like so:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/image.png?email=youremail@email.com
```

You would then catch this serverside and get the user agent string.

The issue with this is with webmail clients like GMail and Hotmail. In these instances the user agent string would be the same as the web browser. Here you would detect the user's webmail client by inspecting the email address, eg. hotmail.com.

There are edge cases such as Google Apps for Business, but this should catch most cases.

Most email senders such as Mailchimp will do mail client analytics for you.