# Link with mailto when the user doesn't have an email handler?

Tags: html, mailto

So,

Imagine that I have this link:

```
<a href="mailto:test@myemail.com">Test</a>
```

How do you deal with people that visit your site and don't have any email handler? What are the possible solutions? Like showing the email, for example? Any other solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This solution requires you putting the email in between the anchor links. Why would you not?

I would not worry about it. Most browsers (all modern ones) would allow a user to right click and copy the email to their clipboard in the worst case. Its not such a mission critical feature that I would worry about it. If they do click it, I believe the browser will ask the user what mail client they would like to associate`mailto` links to.

The only other choice would to allow them to fill out a form that your mail server will generate into an email and then send to the appropriate recipients.

Answer (score 0):

On mouse over it could show a tool tip above the link with the email?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to be dependant on client settings, you ll need to provide the service server side.  Meaning allow ppl to send an email from your site using some simple text box and a SMTP plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this question helpful: [Has anyone ever come up with a way to detect the email program a recipient is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591474/has-anyone-ever-come-up-with-a-way-to-detect-the-email-program-a-recipient-is-us)

Essentially, there's no possible way to check if there's an outside program to handle email, so short of writing a submission forum that automatically sends the email to the intended recipient, there's probably not much you can do.