# mailto - catch users that dont have an email client set up

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

Adding a `mailto:` link on my site, but it occurred to me that it's possible the user may not have a client set up to handle it

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591474/has-anyone-ever-come-up-with-a-way-to-detect-the-email-program-a-recipient-is-us) thread from 3 years ago and was hoping there's something doable now. I don't necessarily need to figure out what's handling their mailto links, but rather if it got handled at all. Is this possible?

Comment: And what do you intend to do if it didn't get handled? Perhaps you should just offer this as an alternative up front?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I would just use the link text as the actual email address, but I'm sure you know that, too.

Comment: @Jon I reckon either a contact form or some popup displaying the email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. =(

The answer in your link still stands today.  The knowledge that something was even capable of handling the event is way to much information to give to a browser.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I was just hoping. It'd be nice to not have to have a contact form on my personal website but meh. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, `mailto:` is very limited, the information is beyond the scope of the browser

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. However, you can get a free account with jotform.com and use that. It works GREAT. Hopefully this can help.